# Ajax call is not returning to success from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

In the code below, I am doing an ajax call and calling a controller '/feedback', and from controller, I am returning a String value as "Y". But everytime, it's redirecting me to error Jsp.

Any help would be appreciated.

Ajax call:

```
document.getElementById("modal_feedback").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        var form = this;
         var name = form.name.value;
         var rating = form.overall.value;
         var msg = form.message.value;
         if(name == "") {
           alert("Please enter your Name");
         form.name.focus();
         e.preventDefault();
         } else if(rating == "") {
            alert("Please select a rating");
         form.overall[0].focus();
         e.preventDefault();
          } else if(msg == "") {
             alert("Please enter your comment in the Message box");
          form.message.focus();
         e.preventDefault();
       }
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "feedbackData.htm?ratingId="+rating+"&msg="+msg,
          success: function(response) {
         console.debug(response);
         if(response == 'Y'){
         $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
         $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
        .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
            $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/icon_pdf.png' />");
          });
    }
    }
  });
  return false;

}, false);
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/feedbackData")
    public @ResponseBody String getFeedbackData(String ratingId, String msg) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        System.out.println("Inside FeedbackController..");
        try{
            feedbackService.updateFeedback(ratingId,msg);
            return "Y";
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Exception in Login :" + e);
            return "N";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're using POST method and sending attribute in the url, this is something wrong,  and why you use feedbackdata.html instead of feedbackdata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your ajax code by adding `dataType : "html"` so that it accepts response as string like below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "feedbackData.htm?ratingId="+rating+"&msg="+msg,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(response) {
        console.debug(response);
        if(response == 'Y'){
            $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
            $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
            .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/icon_pdf.png' />");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Also read `jquery ajax` official documentation for more clarification [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: You can mark this answer as helpful, if it works for you so that it helps others who are facing the same issue. Thanks

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: try `console.log(response)` under `success` function and send your response here.

Comment: Giving me following error on console.                                              Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at eval (eval at evaluate (:85:21), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/TDP/resources/js/feedback-modal.js:36:4)

Comment: are you sure? you have added `dataType: "html",` to your ajax function first?

Comment: Above error was before the datatype:"html" added. Below console error after datatype:"html" added. Also I have added async: "false". Response value returned as "Y"
tdphome.htm:1 Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140100/discussion-between-msv-and-mahesh-singh-chouhan).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the datatype:"html" which start returning the response and not taking to the error.jsp. Updated JS code as below

```
      document.getElementById("modal_feedback").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();   
      var form = this;
      var name = form.name.value;
      var rating = form.overall.value;
      var msg = form.message.value;
          if(name == "") {
             alert("Please enter your Name");
             form.name.focus();
             e.preventDefault();
          } else if(rating == "") {
      alert("Please select a rating");
      form.overall[0].focus();
      e.preventDefault();
      } else if(msg == "") {
         alert("Please enter your comment in the Message box");
         form.message.focus();
         e.preventDefault();
     }
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "feedbackData.htm?ratingId="+rating+"&msg="+msg,
    async : false,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(response) {
        console.debug(response);
        if(response == 'Y'){
        $('#modal_window').html("<div id='message'></div>");
        $('#message').html("<h2>Feedback Form Submitted!</h2>").append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
        }
    },
    error : function(e) {
        alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
  });
   return false;
});
```